# Big problem with mamp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

Well, my problem is that something deleted the phpMyAdmin so I downloaded a new vesion and installed it. (It took me a long time to figure out how to install it) I started up the start page and it gave me a big ugly error that said:Mysql:couldn't connect to server. Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you modify your config file? Look throw config.php in dir with phpmyadmin.
2. Did you start mysql? Something like

/etc/init.d/mysql start
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysqld start

Comment: "ps aux | grep mysql" from shell (ssh) to make known if mysql is started.

Comment: this is the output: julian    3380   0.9  0.1    75516    484 s000  S+    2:59PM   0:00.01 grep mysql

Comment: So you have to start mysql. "/etc/init.d/mysql start" or "/etc/init.d/mysqld start" for Linux (most of distrs). "/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysqld start" for FreeBSD..